# How to import a project into Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, import, yelp

I am attempting to integrate the Yelp API into my iOS app. From the existing yelp documentation for objective C, we downloaded their Xcode project and dragged it into our project. However, when trying to call and import the project in my swift file, we have errors. Here is what I mean:

```
func getYelpData(mapItem:MKMapItem) {
    var term: String = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("term") ?? "") as! String;

    var location: String = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("location") ?? "") as! String
    var APISample: YPAPISample = YPAPISample() // Use of undeclared type 'YPAPISample'
```

and at the top of the class I try to import the YPAPISample like so

```
import YelpAPISample
```

but it does not allow me to do this either.

I'm new to swift programming so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's one of the most regularly asked question regarding Swift on SO.

Apple provided a document here for such purpose:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

In short, you'd need to create a bridge header to import the Objective-C framework. Not all the framework can be import directly in Swift.

---

To add it manually, search bridging in build settings: (Make sure you select `All`)

[image]

Comment: When I create the bridging header with the correctly selected target, I would call: #import <YelpAPISample, YelpAPISample.h> ??

Comment: I didn't see the code but it should be `#import <YelpAPISample/YelpAPISample.h>`

Comment: I think I am having an issue with setting up the bridge file, as I am trying to manually create one. In my build settings, there is no option for Objective C bridging which is strange.

Comment: ailed to import bridging header '/Users/shaheensharifian/park-n-go/Park 'N Go/Park 'N Go-Bridging-Header.h'How does the file paths work... Because Park I put Park 'N Go/Park 'N Go-Bridging-Header.h under the Objective-C Bridging Header, as Park 'N Go-Bridging-Header is the name of my header file. However, an error says:
ailed to import bridging header '/Users/shaheensharifian/park-n-go/Park 'N Go/Park 'N Go-Bridging-Header.h'

Comment: Path is related to `.xcodeproj`. Should be `Park 'N Go/Park 'N Go-Bridging-Header.h`